# using nlog in asp-classic

Tags: asp-classic, nlog

We have a solution with a .net core and we use a classic asp front site.

Our .net libraries use nlog, and I have to implement this feature on the front as well.

I searched the web and found [one example](http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/VBScript-td1685831.html) from an old nlog version (back in 2007) usable as an activex. I try with nlog v4, but it doesn't seem to work.

I saw on the [nlog site](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/13/NLog-Extended_NLog-Web_and_NLog-Windows-Forms.html) that "the classic ASP (so non-ASP.Net) are still in the NLog package (4.0)". What does it mean ? I didn't find any code sample or documentation on this feature.

Can you provide a simple example on how to use nlog in a classic asp page ?

Comment: I'm afraid you simply can't do that. This is meant for ASP.NET and can't be used as-is in classic ASP code. You'll have to find one, or write it yourself.

Comment: In theory it should work? http://weblogs.asp.net/dneimke/65330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this change log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/releases/tag/v3.0) and [this post](http://nlog-project.org/2013/12/14/nlog-3-0.html), starting from version 3.0 `COM Interop` *which provides you to use the library in Classic ASP* support removed from NLog.

You can use [v2.1.0](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/releases/tag/2.1.0) the latest COM Interop supported NLog release by registering the assembly on your web server.

This seems to be the easiest way to accomplish NLog in Classic ASP but with the lacks of number of new features that you may require of course.

Comment: Oh... And what about the " classic ASP (so non-ASP.Net) are still in the NLog package (4.0)" info on the nlog site ? Does it refer to something else ?

Comment: @EricBole-Feysot That post make you confused refers to the NLog 4.0 and yes it should, but does not make any sense at all. As you can see in [NLog/src/NLog at 4.0.0](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/tree/4.0.0/src/NLog) there is no `ComInterop` namespace. On the other hand the namespace available in [NLog/src/NLog at 2.1.0](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/tree/2.1.0/src/NLog). I think they mean [**this**](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/4.0.0/tests/webtest/context.asp) with `the classic ASP (so non-ASP.Net) are still in the NLog package (4.0)`. An old useless test.

Comment: register which assembly? there are 4 .NET and 6 sl(n) folders in the 2.1.0 zip.

Comment: @BeauD'Amore `sl`s stand for Silverlight, just ignore them. You should make a choice from `netXX` builds depending on the installed .Net Framework on the server. I would try `net40` first.

Comment: "The module nlog.dll was loaded but the entry point DLLRegisterServer was not found"... ?.. (using "regsvr32 nlog.dll" from that directory, as administrator).. any clues?

Comment: From my experience decades ago, I had to regsvr32 the dll first, then add it to the COM+ control panel, which is now 'component services'

Comment: Since this is a .NET dll you need to register with `regasm.exe` instead. Have a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jigarme/2008/04/28/how-to-register-net-assembly-for-com-interop/

Comment: FYI versions in the paths may vary. For .NET 4.x `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe` for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156365/discussion-between-beau-damore-and-kul-tigin).